# How to Disable Live Reload Enabled Error in Console While Refreshing Web Page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, console

I'm encountering an issue with live reload being enabled in my web development environment, and it's causing an error message to appear in the console every time I refresh the page. I'm using extension live server, I'd like to disable it temporarily to avoid this error message cluttering my console output.[console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuRG0.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.